# Will SnO2 or SnO form from this reaction?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, redox

I have two possible chemical equations for a reaction between $\ce{SnCl2}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. The first one is:

$$\ce{2SnCl2 + 2H2O +O2 -> 2SnO2 + 4HCl}$$

where the reaction draws on oxygen from the air. The second possibility is:

$$\ce{SnCl2 + H2O -> SnO + 2HCl}$$

I know that in the first reaction, tin is oxidized and oxygen is reduced, but I can't figure out if that reaction is favorable, or if it is possible that it's using oxygen from the air. The second equation is the only other possible reaction that I can find, but it doesn't form the product that we want.

Comment: SnCl2 does react with O2 from air, but slowly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual reaction of tin (II) chloride with water in the presence of air is given [here](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-11941).

$$\ce{6SnCl2 + O2 + 2H2O → 2SnCl4 + 4Sn(OH)Cl}$$

> Tin(II) chloride react with oxygen and water to produce tin(IV) chloride and hydroxotin(II) chloride. Interaction with oxygen and air humidity. This reaction takes place slowly.

As Mithoron noted, **the reaction takes place very, very slowly** and thus get hydrolysed partially to form the basic salt, $\ce{Sn(OH)Cl}$ instead of forming the hydroxide or the oxide.

The basic salt will also form when tin (II) chloride reacts with water in the absence of air, thanks to Gannex.

$$\ce{SnCl2 + H2O ⇄ Sn(OH)Cl + HCl}$$

> Tin(II) chloride react with water to produce hydroxotin(II) chloride
>   and hydrogen chloride. This reaction is proceeds by diluting the
>   solution tin(II) chloride. ([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-652))

As noted earlier, **the reaction is very, very slow** and maintains an equilibrium between the reactants and the products.

However when tin (II) chloride is present in a concentrated, acidified solution, it will form a complex.([source](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-11937))

$$\ce{SnCl2 + H2O → [Sn(H2O)Cl2]}$$

> Tin(II) chloride react with water to produce dichloridoaquatin.
>   Tin(II) chloride - concentrated solution. pH < 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your tin will not spontaneously change oxidation state just from adding water. On dilution, some of the tin (II) chloride may be hydrolyzed, precipitating the basic salt:

$\ce{SnCl2 + H2O -> Sn(OH)Cl + HCl}$

Comment: We did initially mix the SnCl2 with water and the HCl...I don't know if that makes a difference.