# Yellow precipitate in SnCl2 solution

Tags: acid-base, solubility

I have a few small bottles of 0.5M $\ce{SnCl2}$ solution, however solution was prepared about 4 months ago, and there is a yellow precipitate on the bottom of each bottle. Working hypothesis is that this yellow precipitate is $\ce{Sn(OH)Cl}$, and reaction is:

$$\ce{SnCl2 (aq) + H2O (l) ⇌ Sn(OH)Cl (s) + HCl (aq)}$$

([from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_chloride#Chemical_properties)))

I added a few drops of $\ce{HCl}$ to push the equilibrium towards left-hand side, but so far only small part of yellow precipitate is dissolved. Should I add plenty of $\ce{HCl}$ then? If you have any idea on how much, please let me know.

Wikipedia says:

> Therefore, if clear solutions of tin(II) chloride are to be used, it
>   must be dissolved in hydrochloric acid (typically of the same or
>   greater molarity as the stannous chloride) to maintain the equilibrium
>   towards the left-hand side (using Le Chatelier's principle).

do I read it right that I have to add the same volume of $\ce{HCl}$ (0.5M) to my 0.5M $\ce{SnCl2}$? (well, they didn't say that, but sort of hinted)

Thank you very much in advance!

UPDATE: I added decent amount of $\ce{HCl}$, and I still have some yellow precipitate (I think less, than before, but still a rather large amount), and my solution is not transparent, it is whitish-opaque. $\ce{SnCl2}$ solution has to be transparent.

Comment: I'd rather suspect oxidation.

Comment: If you suspect oxidation by the air (oxygen), then I think it is  unlikely, as bottles were full of solution and closed tightly - there was no air (oxygen) access to the solution.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but are you thoroughly agitating it? Increasing surface area always helps the speed of reactions.

Comment: Thank you for asking, @ringo! I spent some tie agitating it and was unable to dissolve all precipitate I had. However, both experiments I needed this solution for, went very well. So I guess it was OK. Experiments I conducted: (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Btaf9AUnjDo (2) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AklooXzB1w8. Here is a picture of my tin hedgehog: https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=331731090491714&set=a.107640622900763.1073741827.100009644765577&type=3&theater

Comment: Other than forming the basic salt, it will particularly form $\ce{H[SnCl3]}$,  [hydrogen trichloridostannate(II)](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-632)  if the concentration of HCl is in excess  or will form an [aqua salt](http://chemiday.com/en/reaction/3-1-0-11937), $\ce{[Sn(H2O)Cl2]}$ if the conc. of SnCl2 is more than that of water. These are the undesirable  side products and will resist the precipitate to dissolve and show whitish opaque color.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54402/will-sno2-or-sno-form-from-this-reaction/54403

Comment: have you tried any other methods to speed it up